# does postfix 2.11 needs to be patched with VDA patch for per user or domain Quota support, when dovecot 2.2.x is used as imap server?

Tags: linux, postfix, ubuntu-14.04, dovecot

does postfix 2.11 needs to be patched  with VDA  patch for per user or domain **Quota support**, when dovecot 2.2.x is used as imap server ? 
Im using ubuntu 14.04 LTS  with postfixadmin 2.3.
i appreciate any useful working guides. thank you

## dovecot -n output

http://pastebin.com/LCPmQ5Th

## master.cf

http://pastebin.com/db6B2uMP

## cat dovecot-sql.conf.ext

driver = mysql
connect = host=127.0.0.1 dbname=postfixadmin user=postfixadmin password=XXXXXXXX
default_pass_scheme = MD5-CRYPT

password_query = SELECT username as user, password FROM mailbox WHERE username='%u';
user_query = SELECT maildir AS home,5000 AS uid,5000 AS gid,    CONCAT("*:bytes=",quota) AS quota_rule FROM mailbox WHERE username = '%n@%d' 
                AND active=1;

Comment: Put four blank spaces at the beginning of each line to format as a code block. You can select in the edit window and use the `{}` button for this.

Comment: i used pastebin link, ithink that would be readable

Comment: #main.cf 
http://pastebin.com/H9HEmzkP

Answer (score 0):

If `postfix` do not attempt to perform LDA itself and invoke dovecot's `deliver` instead, then `postfix` do not need to know about quotas at all.

If you have used `postfixadmin` for virtual domains management, then you already have everything you need for quota restrictions. You have to modify `dovecot`'s SQL query to fetch user's quotas:

```
user_query = SELECT maildir AS home, \
                    26 AS uid, \
                    26 AS gid, \
                    CONCAT("*:bytes=",quota) AS quota_rule \
               FROM mailbox \
              WHERE username = '%n@%d' \
                AND active=1;
```

(do not blindly copy-paste that example, use it as template)

Then you have to setup quota plugin and warning service in the `dovecot.conf`

## **UPDATED:**

```
. . . . . .
# this line enable quota plugin!
mail_plugins            = quota

# here is the plugin's configuration
plugin {
  quota                 = maildir:User quota
  quota_rule            = Junk:ignore
  quota_rule2           = Trash:storage=+100M
  quota_warning         = storage=90%% quota-warning 90 %u %d
  quota_warning2        = storage=80%% quota-warning 80 %u %d
  quota_exceeded_message = ERROR:422 - Mailbox full, sorry.
. . . . .
}
. . . . .
service quota-warning {
  executable    = script /path/to/the/overquota.sh
  user          = $mail_uid
  group         = $mail_gid
  unix_listener quota-warning {
    user        = $mail_uid
    group       = $mail_gid
  }
}
. . . . .
```

`overquota.sh` should look like that:

```
#!/bin/sh
cat << EOT | /usr/local/libexec/dovecot/dovecot-lda -d $2 -o "plugin/quota=maildir:User quota:noenforcing"
From: postmaster@$3
To: $2
Subject: == Quota warning ==
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"

Your mailbox is $1% full, so clean up your mess, please!

EOT
exit 0
####
```

When dovecot's `deliver` try to store the message into inbox, it check whether the quota was reached predefined thresholds 80% and 90% or no. If so - quota-warning service is invoked and script is launched, that place a warning message into mailbox - without further quota checkout.

Comment: hi thank for reply, im using dovecot as lda ,the emails seem to send/receive successfully but i cant implement per user quota, i also implemented your suggestion but dovecot quota didnt work, heres my #dovecot -n  in the original post

Comment: @satriani_sherpa I've update my answer